# compose a dataframe from a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem a bit complicated I'm stuck on it ,

I have this data frame from my json file

```
time           other_json                                               value
11:20     {'column1':'S', 'column2': '0000', 'column3': 'jj'}            10
11:25     {'column1':'50', 'column2': '11', 'column3': '12'}             1
11:30     {'column4':'50', 'column6': '11'}                              11
```

and the results I want is to have a final dataframe in this form :

```
time      column1  column2 column3 column4  column6 value
11:20         S       0000    jj      Nan      Nan    10
11:25         50        11    12      Nan      Nan     1
11:30         Nan       Nan   Nan      11       12    11
```

if you have any ideas of how I can do this .
thank you

Comment: `df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('other_json').values.tolist()))`

Comment: This is actually better than my answer.

Comment: but dont working well

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['11:20', '11:25', '11:30'],
             'other_json': [{'column1':'S', 'column2': '0000', 'column3': 'jj'},
                           {'column1':'50', 'column2': '11', 'column3': '12'},
                           {'column4':'50', 'column6': '11'}],
             'value': [10, 1, 11]})

pd.concat([df[['time', 'value']], pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.other_json.values)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>time</th>\n      <th>value</th>\n      <th>column1</th>\n      <th>column2</th>\n      <th>column3</th>\n      <th>column4</th>\n      <th>column6</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>11:20</td>\n      <td>10</td>\n      <td>S</td>\n      <td>0000</td>\n      <td>jj</td>\n      <td>NaN</td>\n      <td>NaN</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>11:25</td>\n      <td>1</td>\n      <td>50</td>\n      <td>11</td>\n      <td>12</td>\n      <td>NaN</td>\n      <td>NaN</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2</th>\n      <td>11:30</td>\n      <td>11</td>\n      <td>NaN</td>\n      <td>NaN</td>\n      <td>NaN</td>\n      <td>50</td>\n      <td>11</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a small solution but I'm not sure that it is optimal

```
result=pd.DataFrame()
dict_= {}
for i in range (0,mydataframe.shape[0]):
    dict_[i]=mydataframe.other_json[i]
    df1=pd.DataFrame([dict_[i]])
    result = result.append(df1, sort=False)
```

Then after I will concatenate with the old dataframe